# Detecting rectangle shape on image and adding a div over it Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wonder if following is possible at all:

I have an image inside a div (as background image of div). The image is similar to excel sheet. Now, I want to create a input tag or contenteditable div when user clicks on any cell of the image. The border of the created div or input should be equal to cell size on the image.

Can someone atleast point me in some direction?

Following solution looks promising:

http://www.travisberry.com/2011/05/write-text-anywhere-with-html5-canvas/

But has the alignment problem with the image cells.

Comment: Why not skip the image pretending to be (similar to ) an Excel sheet, and use styled `<input>` elements in the `<div>` instead, and make your life far, far easier?

Comment: If for some odd reason you can't do what @DavidThomas suggests (that's really the best way to do that), you can use a [HTML Image Map](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Unsure how experienced you are, so forgive me if this is pedantic.
But-  I'd recommend playing around with JQuery functions to grab dimension variables, and then base the logic on what you discover.

For instance:

```
$( "img" ).click(function() {
     var height = $( this ).css( "height" );
     var width = $( this ).css( "width" );
     var ratio = height/width;

     if( min_rectangle_ratio < ratio < max_rectangle_ratio)
     {
          //set div dimensions to what you detected above
     }
 });
```